# Run multiple chrome (profiles) instances for automation task

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, multiple-instances

I want to run multiple chrome instances with different profiles(each profile have their cookies) to do some task simultaneous . For example I want to search on Google with 2 accounts(each account have their proxy).

I use Visual Studio Community 2015.

This is what I do until now (without proxies):

```
namespace ChromeBot
{
    class Program
    {
        public static object Application { get; private set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Set specific profile for Google Chrome
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/conta/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/");
            options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.AddArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 1");


            //Create the reference for our browser 
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 12));


            //Navigate to Google Page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");


            //Find the element
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));


            //Perform ops
            element.SendKeys("cars");


            // Set specific profile for Google Chrome1
            var options1 = new ChromeOptions();
            options1.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/conta/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/");
            options1.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            options1.AddArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 2");


            //Create the reference for our browser 1
            IWebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver(options1);

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 12));

            //Navigate to Google Page 1
            driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

            //Find the element
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));


            //Perform ops
            element.SendKeys("smartphones");
        }
    }
}
```

When run this code open each profile and do nothing..

Any help?

Comment: Thanks for help. Works fine if copy entire profile to another location and set it to user-data-dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user launches chrome through chromedriver it opens a new instance of chrome browser and locks user-data-dir. hence if any other instance tries to open with same user-data-dir, the second instance do not responds.

Please launch each chrome instance with different user-data-dir.